# Linked account +100 rep bonus also applied to account with 200

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, association-bonus

Not sure if it is a bug or not, but it *feels* like a bug to me. When I got to 200 rep on SO the other day I got +100 rep to all my accounts **including** SO. So my rep jumped up to 300 on SO.

Considering there are others on SO with rep between 200 and 300 I think it is possible that the +100 was supposed to apply *only* to the linked accounts, not to the account with 200+.

Comment: I think this is how it's supposed to work. The first association gives you a bonus on **both** sites, subsequent ones give you the bonus only on the **new** site.

Comment: +1 ChrisF it worked for me that way, which seems consistent.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Quite strange I reached 200 rep on SO weeks ago but I got the +100 bonus on SO only today. Today I asked my first question on meta, maybe that's the motivation.

Comment: I got over 200 on one of the other projects first, having between 200 and 300 on SO for some time is completely normal in this case.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's not a bug.
The bonus applies for both the sites, but you get the bonus once for each site. The next time you associate your Stack Overflow account to another Stack Exchange site, you will not get any bonus, on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

You can have rep. between 200 - 300 by placing a bounty for example or downvotes. So it's not a bug on your account.

Comment: In either cases, the OP would not get +100; in both the cases you listed, the OP would lose reputation.