# Sudden rep surge

Tags: support, reputation

My StackOverflow reputation suddenly increased by 101 points. It shows, in stackoverflow.com/reputation, that I've always had this reputation bonus: when I first created my account on 2/23 it says that I had 105 reputation, even though this is impossible to start with that much rep.

Additional info: I had not been able to access StackOverflow for ~5 minutes before this happened. Also, I've already tried the "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button on the bottom of the stackoverflow.com/reputation page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You reached 200 reputation and got the [association bonus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#login).

The bonus is not given a date in the reputation log, for some reason.

Comment: Hmmm... thanks. I never knew about this. I guess the association bonus also gives me a +100 on the site I got to 200 rep from.

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp: Yes, it gives you +100 on every site.

Comment: hold on, looks like [he have 200+ on Stack Overflow only](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161986/javaandcsharp?tab=accounts), where did he get 100+ on Stack Overflow itself?

Comment: @YOU That's [status-bydesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/linked-account-100-rep-bonus-also-applied-to-account-with-200).

Comment: Hum, I see, strange enough though. Thanks @Anna Lear.

Comment: @YOU Yeah, it surprised me too the other day when I went looking to see if it was a bug.