# I earned 10pts but later score increased by 100pts with no reason. Is it a bug?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linked account +100 rep bonus also applied to account with 200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/linked-account-100-rep-bonus-also-applied-to-account-with-200)

today(2011-08-22) I earned only 10 points on reputation on http://stackoverflow.com, but later in the evening my score increased by 100 more points without any reason visible in the reputation history.

Is this a bug, a magic gift, or what ?

Comment: Short answer: It's a magic gift.  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You joined User Experience today, and you had more than 200 points on Stack Overflow: [100 bonus on both sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57897/the-faqs-should-add-clarifying-detail-to-the-100-bonus-for-associating-accounts)!

[Your reputation report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) will also list "rep from bonuses: 100" for associating accounts.

(You should also have received a top-bar notification for that, as far as I know.)

Comment: Good work, I missed that.