# Bonus reputation

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linked account +100 rep bonus also applied to account with 200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/linked-account-100-rep-bonus-also-applied-to-account-with-200)

I made an account on Code Review, with the same OpenID as Stack Overflow, and I got 100 bonus reputation. Later I went on Stack Overflow and realized my reputation there was up 100 as well. Why? Is there any relationship between Code Review and Stack Overflow?

Comment: Have a look at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/linked-account-100-rep-bonus-also-applied-to-account-with-200