# Why did I earn 100 points in my Stackoverflow account when logged in other stack axchange site

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should all linked accounts get the 100 bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus)
>   [Linked account +100 rep bonus also applied to account with 200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/linked-account-100-rep-bonus-also-applied-to-account-with-200)

I know that people with 200 points or more on stackoverflow, gets 100 bonus points when logs in other stack exchange forum.

But happens that I not only got 100 points at programmers, I also got them in stack overflow. Is that a bug? If I go to my reputation page on stackoverflow I cant see this 100 bonus points being tracked there as all my other pointers earned are.

Comment: All the linked accounts get the 100 reputation bonus. Use it well! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. You get that 100 rep so you can post answers, and chat and all that because you are already a trusted SE user.

I'm guessing your question will be downvoted, though, because it's already been asked before on MSO...

Comment: No downvote, just closing as duplicate. :)

Comment: I wonder why I get 100 rep on my STACKOVERFLOW account. I understand that I should get those 100 rep on the other site, but why on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, he was lucky :-)

Comment: @RenatoGama, on SO, as a kind of reward for 'good' conduct.

Comment: RenatoGama - SO is part of the linked accounts. You get it only once though, it's not like you'll get 100 more in SO when linking another account. Hope it's more clear now? @JunkIE (pun intended ;)) - nah, don't think luck is involved. Believe me, if people wanted to downvote, we would have already seen it. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, great pun, I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 with Firefox 7

Comment: Hi, Already i have 920 reputations, suddenly it changed to 100

Comment: @PREMKUMAR, take it up with the moderators of the site. You should be able to merge your accounts.

Comment: Hi,Please tell me how to merge my accounts?. Please guide me

Comment: @PREMKUMAR, I've flagged your comment so a moderator can look at your account. Cheers.

Comment: @PREMKUMAR, here's the correct Q&A http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist

Comment: @GUIJunkie Nothing to see here with PremKumar; he was deleted due to many rule violations and came back here yesterday playing stupid about it. He's all taken care of ;)