# I just earned 200 points and was rewarded an extra 100 points at Stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linked account +100 rep bonus also applied to account with 200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/linked-account-100-rep-bonus-also-applied-to-account-with-200)

I know that I get 100 points on all other sites that I have a user on but why do I get these 100 points on SO where I just made 200 points? Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: This works as designed. You get the 100 points on the site with 200 only the first time.

Comment: ok, I found this here too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/linked-account-100-rep-bonus-also-applied-to-account-with-200

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57897/the-faq-should-add-clarifying-detail-about-the-100-account-association-bonus