# Should the Association Bonus be given to the account crossing 200 rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, linked-accounts

On Stack Overflow, I crossed 200 reputation and got the 100 rep association bonus on all my other accounts. I also got 100 rep on Stack Overflow. Giving an Association Bonus to my other Stack Exchange accounts is completely understandable, but what is the use of giving the Association Bonus to the account which gain 200 rep?

I have gone through this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/linked-account-100-rep-bonus-also-applied-to-account-with-200), but it only explains how it works.

Comment: You gain the association bonus on **all** your accounts across the network. You get the bonus for associating, so it is only fair that your SO account is not exempted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know that, but question is what is the use of giving +100 to the account which gained 200 rep

Comment: Fairness. Period.

Comment: @Antony Fairness, a good point, But somewhere on Stack Overflow I read Reputation is to be hard earned, and users should work hard for it, In that context i think its unfair

Comment: I see your point here, and it makes some degree of sense. But Antony's point is probably the winner. As far as rep being "hard earned", that's true, but 100 points is basically nothing. And there's no way to abuse this, you only get the association bonus *once*.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not abusing it, but I don't see any point of giving it also

Comment: The point is simplicity. Granting 100 rep to all associated accounts is simpler than granting to all bar one. When one account would be excluded, it's just a matter of time before "*Why didn't I get 100 rep for associating?*"-type questions pop up.

Comment: Here's another issue it avoids: If you have two accounts with _almost_ 200 rep, you don't have to worry about which one gets the bonus and which doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, what @kapep says. Say you've got an account at 199 and another at 120. You gain +5 on the first, go over 200 and get +100 on the other one. Then, if that first one _didn't_ get +100 as well, suddenly that _other one_ would have the highest rep. That doesn't sound right, does it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We operate like DirecTV here, you and your friend (in this case, yourself) both get a reward for the association/referral.  When you have 9 users on 9 sites and a year from now one doesn't have the bonus...why? That makes even less sense, so we award it across all sites, intentionally.

We can manually remove yours if you're that upset about the free points, but we'd rather not.