# Can reputation across stack exchange sites be pooled?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I ask because things like up-voting require reputation, but in areas where I'm knowledgeable, I don't have many questions, and the ones I do have already been asked, and answered well, making reputation hard to acquire.   (I'm assuming the only practical way to gain reputation is to ask and answer questions).

Across the whole network, I've got more than sufficient reputation, but not on those sites where I have knowledge and would most like to up-vote.

Comment: Get to 200 on any site and you will be able to upvote everywhere.

Comment: I have 10K rep on MSO.  Does that make me qualified to delete posts on Cooking?  What about someone who has 5K rep on Bicycle.SE.  Should they be able to close questions on Programmers simply because they know enough about bikes?  Pooling reputation is a bad idea for simply that reason.

Comment: Why the down votes?  Is this not a good question?  Search revealed nothing...

Comment: @Phil: [voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): feature requests may be downvoted because others disagree with the feature request.

Comment: Accepted edits will net you +2 reputation points if accepted, until you get 1000 points that way or reach 2000 reputation points, whichever comes first. So, asking and answering aren't the only way to gain reputation.

Comment: @AlEverett IIRC, hitting 2K doesn't actually prevent suggested edits from giving rep; you just have to switch to Tag Wikis so you're still suggesting.

Comment: @psubsee2003 clearly not - we try to do away with bike-shedding problems as much as possible.  ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/linked-account-100-rep-bonus-also-applied-to-account-with-200). When you have an account on the stack exchange network with 200 rep or above, you get 100 association bonus on any other stack exchange site, You will be given 100 rep association bonus.

Apart from that there is no other way you can pool reputation and I don't think it will be a good idea to pool reputation. That you have moderation privileges (10k+ rep) on christianity doesn't mean you are fit to moderate stack overflow

Comment: I.e. your starting reputation will be `101` on every other site. Enough power to up-vote but slightly short of what's required to down-vote.