# Can the association bonus be applied to the base account?

Tags: support, linked-accounts, association-bonus, association

Does the account that originally got the 200 rep. get the bonus 100 rep. on its own account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's how it is designed: the first account to get 200 will get a bonus of 100 like all the other accounts.  See [Linked account +100 rep bonus also applied to account with 200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90687/300411).