# Meta restrictions even if other accounts have enough rep?

Tags: discussion

Why, even if you have a lot of reputation on one site, can you not participate in meta on another you have just joined? Should you be able to partcipate straight away? After all, I assume that the feature is just to stop spam users, but you're obviously not a spam account if you have tens, hundreds or even thousands of reputation points? Is it something worth changing, or is it to make sure the users get a feel for a site before starting discussion?

Comment: @gnat no it's not. OP is well aware of the restriction, and ask ***WHY*** it's in place.

Comment: @ShadowWizard per my reading of the question OP is not aware that there is no restriction indeed. "if you have a lot of reputation on one site" (>200, gives association bonus) you _can_ participate in meta on another. Meta participation requires 5 rep, this is more than covered by 100 rep bonus

Comment: @gnat thanks, I read again and got it. Found a better dupe though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard checked your better dupe - as far as I can tell it is a dupe itself :)

Comment: @gnat lol, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No (to most of the questions in your question).  Every community and its Meta are different.  This feature is not just to stop spam.

It is important for any user to start to understand the protocols and culture of a site new to them before starting to try and change them, or consuming the community's Meta users' time explaining them over and over again.

The protocols and culture of the new site may be quite dissimilar to what the user has experienced on the one site where the user has a lot of reputation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have at [least 200 rep on any site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/linked-account-100-rep-bonus-also-applied-to-account-with-200) then every time you join a new site you start with 101 rep on that site. That gets you over most new user restrictions including participating in meta.

The 200 rep on one site is to ensure you know your way around. Hopefully you'd have enough knowldge to understand you need to properly research your questions before asking anywhere including on your new site's meta thereby obviating the need to ask your question in the first place.

So users with "hundreds or even thousands of reputation points" are catered for already just as you wanted, and those with tens just need to participate more first.